# How do I create a nuget packages.config file from the command line?

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package-restore

When I run a command like `nuget install pdfsharp` to add an external library to the project, the library is installed but as mentioned in [the nuget documentation](http://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/tools/nuget.exe-cli-reference) the command does not modify the project or packages.config.

Since I'm adding to an empty hello world, how do I create this `packages.config` file for nuget to later use `nuget restore`? I'm not finding in the documentation the format of this file.

Answer (score 0):

`nuget install` Will add the package but will not modify the project or xml config, See - https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/tools/nuget.exe-cli-reference

> Installs a package into the current project but does not modify the project or packages.config.

Try using the powershell commandlets, See - https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/tools/powershell-reference#install-package

```
Install-Package pdfsharp
```

Comment: Powershell is only available from visual studio, which defeats the purpose of running things from the command line.

Comment: You can, you just need to import the cmdlets, check this blog post out - http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/mattward/archive/2011/06/12/InstallingNuGetPackagesOutsideVisualStudio.aspx